# Packer shell provisioner reports running successfully, but didn't do anything

Tags: azure, packer

I am trying to use packer to simply launch a VM, run a single shell script, and then store a new image. I am using Azure, and when I run packer, it appears to complete successfully, but then when I make a VM from the new image, it appears that the script had no effect. The script is just for testing, and should create a file in the home directory, but there is nothing there when I login.

Here is my packer config file:

```
 {
   "builders": [
     {
       "type": "azure-arm",

       "client_id": "...",
       "client_secret": "...",
       "subscription_id": "...",
       "tenant_id": "...",

       "os_type": "Linux",
       "image_publisher": "Canonical",
       "image_offer": "UbuntuServer",
       "image_sku": "16.04-LTS",

       "ssh_pty" : "true",

       "capture_container_name": "container",
       "capture_name_prefix": "prefix",
       "resource_group_name": "rg",
       "storage_account": "sa",

       "location": "West US"
     }
   ],
   "provisioners": [
     {
       "type": "shell",
       "script": "test.sh"
     }
   ]
 }
```

And here is my script (test.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash -e
echo "This is only a test!" >> ~/test_script_output.txt
```

This is the output from the build:

```
azure-arm output will be in this color.

==> azure-arm: Running builder ...
    azure-arm: Creating Azure Resource Manager (ARM) client ...
==> azure-arm: Creating resource group ...
==> azure-arm:  -> ResourceGroupName : 'packer-Resource-Group-4zt0csjrzl'
==> azure-arm:  -> Location          : 'West US'
==> azure-arm:  -> Tags              :
==> azure-arm: Validating deployment template ...
==> azure-arm:  -> ResourceGroupName : 'packer-Resource-Group-4zt0csjrzl'
==> azure-arm:  -> DeploymentName    : 'pkrdp4zt0csjrzl'
==> azure-arm: Deploying deployment template ...
==> azure-arm:  -> ResourceGroupName : 'packer-Resource-Group-4zt0csjrzl'
==> azure-arm:  -> DeploymentName    : 'pkrdp4zt0csjrzl'
==> azure-arm: Getting the VM's IP address ...
==> azure-arm:  -> ResourceGroupName   : 'packer-Resource-Group-4zt0csjrzl'
==> azure-arm:  -> PublicIPAddressName : 'packerPublicIP'
==> azure-arm:  -> NicName             : 'packerNic'
==> azure-arm:  -> Network Connection  : 'PublicEndpoint'
==> azure-arm:  -> IP Address          : '000.000.000.000' <redacted>
==> azure-arm: Waiting for SSH to become available...
==> azure-arm: Connected to SSH!
==> azure-arm: Provisioning with shell script: test.sh
==> azure-arm: Querying the machine's properties ...
==> azure-arm:  -> ResourceGroupName : 'packer-Resource-Group-4zt0csjrzl'
==> azure-arm:  -> ComputeName       : 'pkrvm4zt0csjrzl'
==> azure-arm:  -> OS Disk           : 'https://sa.blob.core.windows.net/images/pkros4zt0csjrzl.vhd'
==> azure-arm: Powering off machine ...
==> azure-arm:  -> ResourceGroupName : 'packer-Resource-Group-4zt0csjrzl'
==> azure-arm:  -> ComputeName       : 'pkrvm4zt0csjrzl'
==> azure-arm: Capturing image ...
==> azure-arm:  -> ResourceGroupName : 'packer-Resource-Group-4zt0csjrzl'
==> azure-arm:  -> ComputeName       : 'pkrvm4zt0csjrzl'
==> azure-arm: Deleting resource group ...
==> azure-arm:  -> ResourceGroupName : 'packer-Resource-Group-4zt0csjrzl'
```

Comment: You don't supply any prof of your statement "when I make a VM from the new image, it appears that the script had no effect."

Comment: Most likely this is just an error in your workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so there were two things I was mission.

Number one, I had to deprovision with waagent so the VM would boot properly. Apparently, [this is required by the azure-arm type](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/azure.html#deprovision). Number two: now that the user account is being deleted, I had to change the script to affect something outside the home directory. So I just had it create a new file on the root of the drive.

This is my new provisioners section:

```
"provisioners": [
  {
    "type": "shell",
    "execute_command": "chmod +x {{ .Path }}; {{ .Vars }} sudo '{{ .Path }}'",
    "script": "test.sh",
    "skip_clean": "true"
  },
  {
    "type": "shell",
    "execute_command": "chmod +x {{ .Path }}; {{ .Vars }} sudo -E sh '{{ .Path }}'",
    "inline_shebang": "/bin/sh -x",
    "inline": [
      "/usr/sbin/waagent -force -deprovision+user && export HISTSIZE=0 && sync"
    ],
    "skip_clean": "true"
  }
]
```

And here is my new script:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
echo "This is only a test!" >> /test_script_output.txt
```

Side note: I had to add "skip_clean" to each provisioner because it would fail to delete the scripts every time. I don't know why yet.